# Hosting an internal php web application on a public web server

Tags: web, hosting, internal, privacy-policy

How do i host an  internal php web application on a public web server .

i need to host a private   web site on the web. I can create a login but have some concerns.

If someone knows a link after the login , how can i stop him to go to that link?

eg

my web site www.myapp.com

this will ask for a login

when the login happens , he goes to www.myapp/welcome.php

How can i stop some one typing www.myapp/welcome.php and bypassing the login?

Regards

Azhar

Answer (score 0):

You can set a session:

```
<?php
//user login
if($password=="1234") {
session_start();
$_SESSION["logged"]="jep";
//redirect to secret site
header("Location: http://myapp/secret.php");
}
?>
```

And check if the user is logged in on your private site

```
<?php
session_start()
if(isset($_SESSION["logged"])){
//user logged in
}else{
header("Location: http://myapp.com");
//send user to home and
die()
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks , thats wonderfull , so in wordpress i just add this text to the top of the page or do i have to install a plugin to run php scripts

Comment: Wordpress is written in php... Im not shure but i think you can just add it.

Comment: You could also use <?php if(is_user_logged_in()){}else{header("Location: myapp.com/wp-login.php")}?> in wordpress

Comment: Hi Jonas,I assume the starting of the sesion has been done by word press.  I run the second part                                                                  <?php
session_start()
if(isset($_SESSION["logged"])){
//user logged in
}else{
header("Location: http://myapp.com");
//send user to home and
die()
}
?>                                                                                                              I get an error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) , what could be wrong?

Comment: And do you think the wordpress login session will still persist , when i am in a different application? Can you please help?